# Use filter to return array where object value matches

Tags: javascript, filter

I have 3 device tabs that should only display items that exist in that device.
On each tab I have the device ID and an array of items that each contain the platform ID. I am trying to filter the array of items to only contain matching items.

```
const id = 1;

const items = [
    {
    id: 1
        title: "foo"
        device: 1
    },
  {
    id: 2
        title: "bar"
        device: 1
    },
  {
    id: 3
        title: "baz"
        device: 2
    }
]


expected = [
    {
    id: 1
        title: "foo"
        device: 1
    },
  {
    id: 2
        title: "bar"
        device: 1
    }
 ]
```

My current failed attempt:

```
offers.filter(key => {
    if (key.platformId === platform) {
      return;
    }
  });
```

Comment: You already mention `.filter()`, so... What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your code indentation and formatting seems a little bit weird, here you go.

```js
const expected = items.filter((item) => item.device == id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filteredArray = offers.filter((item) => item.device === id)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful